# How to use more than one widget in a Django field?

Tags: python, django, forms, widget

I have a specific field in a form which needs to have a custom attribute AND we styled as a password box. Currently I have:

```
login_password = forms.CharField(label=(u'password'))
```

But I need both of these:

```
widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'password'})
widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False)
```

How can I make it so the field uses these two widgets? I've read about `MultiWidget` but I'm not sure if this is what I need to use or how exactly to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PasswordInput` accepts `attrs` as well.

```
login_password = forms.CharField(label=u'password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False, attrs={'placeholder': 'password'}))
```

Comment: Oh sweet, didn't realize that. But in the even I did need multiple widgets, how could I achieve that?

Comment: @MaxMackie It is very general question. And it has the same answer as even more general question: "If I have two classes, how can I make the class that combines these two?". And specific answer comes from specific task: sometimes you can use `MultiWidget`, sometimes you inherit from one class and borrow some methods from another, sometimes (never saw it) direct inheritance from two parents is possible. And in many cases all you need to do is to google and find existing solution. :-)